# How to run gitlab locally over network

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Hello I have setup gitlab over docker and I created a repository then added simple readme file. I am trying to access to the repo from other computers in the same network but I cannot. I setup gitlab to this http://gitlab.local:30080/ url. What should I do to clone repo into other computers and work on local server ?

Answer (score 1):

Where did you specify the dns entry for gitlab.local?

you need some DNS Server which is able to resolve gitlab.local to the IP of the host your docker container is running on.

Did you expose the Port from the container to the Host?

Comment: hello thank you for response. I have followed this tutorial to set up https://medium.com/@pranay.urkude/how-to-setup-gitlab-ci-locally-a8bfe273ce60

Comment: the tutorial edits /etc/hosts and tells the host that under 127.0.0.1 (local loopback interface) gitlab.local gets resolved...

if you want to access this URL from another Computer you have to modify the hosts file of the other Computers too (to the LAN ip, but a bad idea anyway) or have a DNS record in your LANs DNS server which is pointing to the host

Comment: do you have any tutorial for that. I am unity developer and trying to set up local gitlab for our game to collab

Comment: reaching the url is not a must. I just want to use git clone then pull and push like regular github or gitlab. Should I again set DNS server for that ?

Comment: About the DNS entry: you propably should contact your LAN Admin for that..

This should be a very basic configuration but still is very specific on your local setup where nobody here can help you without knowing the details

Answer (score 0):

you must published the port from docker container to the one port from host.

after do this, if you use a linux OS add the record like this in **/etc/hosts** file.

```
192.168.1.10 gitlab.local
```

if you use a Windows OS add the record into the **C:Windows\System32\drivers\etc** HostFile

now you can access gitlab with this urlon the any network computer that edit host file an add record above:

```
 http://gitlab.local:30080/
```

**notice:** the firewall must be off or add firewall-rule for gitlab and port on any computer that you use